# Data Persistence in ViewData verses tempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewdata

I was wondering how long Data can persist in the ViewData dictionary.  I know data can't persist that long in TempData (less than an hour).  So how long can it last in ViewData?  Is there another Data dictionary That will persist Data for a long time.  I know it is starting to sound like I want a session variable and that is very un-MVC, but is there any other way I can get data from a control to a view without passing it directly as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering how long Data can persist in the ViewData dictionary

It lasts from the moment you put it there to the moment the request ends, i.e. the page is rendered and sent to the client.

> I know data can't persist that long in TempData (less than an hour)

`TempData` is like Session but persists only until the next request. So it could be like seconds, minutes, hours, days, ...

> I know it is starting to sound like I want a session variable and that is very un-MVC

I wouldn't say *un-MVCish*, I would say *un-RESTfulish*.

> Is there another Data dictionary That will persist Data for a long time

Yes, the Session, your underlying data storage (like a database or something), cookies, application scope, cache, ... it will all depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: So if someone opens a page, and ViewData was set on a controller, and they leave that page open for an hour or so, then, they can not count on that variable persisting for that length of time?

Comment: @DmainEvent, no you cannot count on something like this. You set ViewData in the controller, the contoller returns a view, the view renders, it generates HTML and at the moment this rendering ends ViewData dies along with all contents.

Comment: Is there some event or something that I can detect to see when the ViewData is emptied, so I can send out an alert to the user and then make them navigate to a different page?

Comment: @DmainEvent, ViewData is emptied much earlier than you can send whatever to the user. As I said in my answer once the page is rendered and ready to be sent to the user, ViewData no longer exists.

Comment: TempData does not persist till next request but until you read it. The getter function of the index property deletes the entry. Therefore TempData can be greatly used for scenarios with multiple pages like wizzards. However, after read, you need to write the content back again if you want to keep it further.

Comment: Darin, how long does TempData is persisted if I don't ever read it? Will it be kept persisted until the next server restart?